# Network is disabled in lubuntu 17

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager

I just installed a fresh lubuntu 17 os. I have also installed the proprietary wifi driver. I can connect to internet via ethernet. There are no wifi network being listed.

When running sudo lshw -C network this command i got

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: 9c:2a:70:d2:4d:fb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7c00000-f7c07fff
```

Any way to get wifi network showing in my panel? BTW the network manager is visible in the panel :)

Comment: DISABLED usually means that the switch or key combination is set to turn off the wireless. Confirm: `rfkill list all` Any hard blocks? Find that switch and switch it!

Comment: @chili555 yes there is one `0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
`

Comment: sorry to bother u agian but how do i switch it?

Comment: What brand and model laptop is it?

Comment: @chili555 dell inspiron

Comment: Dell Inspiron what? 15-5000? 13-3000? Or what?

Comment: @chili555 i google on hard block and i got my wifi working after I turned it on via my keyboard. Thanks mate

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected.